# Bootstrap 4.1 carousel item title and text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using last version of Bootsrap

I want to add Title and text to carousel-item.

but the p Code, stay in the same line,

and it should be after the h5 code.

Here is some of my code:

https://www.codeply.com/go/3qfv388vII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's the d-flex class causing it.
If you change this:

```
<div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

to this:

```
<div class="custom-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

and add this to the your stylesheet:

```
.custom-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

you get the desired result.

**Edit**

To only use bootstrap classes u can instead add the `flex-column` class like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

Comment: yea, it's working. but I think there is best solution without this, something with bootstrap

Comment: then you can instead add flex-column class from bootstrap, will update my answer

Comment: class="d-flex flex-column" is the same as writing style="display:flex; flex-direction:column" without bootstrap